# DHCP v6 client MAC address

Tags: dhcp

I am new to DHCPv6 ..In DHCPv4 we have **chaddr** field to get the Client MAC address from the DHCP message..Similarly how to get the Client MAC address in DHCPv6. RFC doesn't give this details..Could you pls suggest if any other option available?

Answer (score 1):

This should be "encoded" in the [link-local](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) IPv6 address, which the client needs even before contacting the DHCP server, in other words, the MAC address is part of the link-local address.

Comment: but in DHCPv4 server maintains each client MAC address know ..Here how server maintains?

Answer (score 0):

Check dhcpy6d at http://dhcpy6d.ifw-dresden.de which addresses exactly this problem.